# How to use regular expression in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL,I have table called constructions where there is a column called phone, phone numbers are in format 9876543210 but I want to clean the column wherever there are alphabets and symbols.

I was using:

```
select * from constructions where phone like '[a-Z]%';
```

but this is wrong, i guess it works in SQL-Server.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: What do you mean it's wrong? Is it executing fine? Is it returning data you don't expect? You need to specify what is wrong.

Comment: how about using REGEXP ?

Comment: @mb1987 And that error is?

Comment: i am sorry it is executing, but not giving expected result, there is data in column like USA,Canada but it is not returning any rows with this select statement

Comment: It looks like you've violated the 
[Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) that's the backbone of proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Try to avoid having comma-separated values in columns as these are really obnoxious to work with and can't be indexed very well.

Answer (score 0):

No to SQL Server unless you add a regular expression utility function. You have the built in find replace functions but those are very simple.

For MySQL look to the reference manual here >>> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `LIKE` use the [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) version that works with regular expressions.